# Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with Windows 10 Wi-Fi problem when booting into Ubuntu from GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, grub2, windows-10

I have recently bought an HP (15-bs1xx) Laptop.

I used *install Ubuntu alongside with Windows* to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) with preinstalled Windows 10.

Everything is working well and good in Windows, but in Ubuntu I faced Wi-Fi connectivity issues. I searched several forums and disabled *secure boot*, and *fast startup* and restarted my laptop, then Wi-Fi problem got sorted out, but GRUB didn't appear during startup (was automatically booting into Windows OS).

Then I used live USB and changed the booting order from Ubuntu terminal using `sudo -o efibootmgr 0002,0001` to the order I wanted. The GRUB menu appeared this time after restart, but the Wi-Fi problem started again, "Wi-Fi adaptor not found" (only in Ubuntu).

How can I fix this? I desperately want to have the GRUB menu as well as Wi-Fi connectivity.

I also have messed up in the command prompt:

[image: terminal output for efibootmgr -v]